# Открыть документ на C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Программа на C# WPF. Нужно при нажатии на кнопку открыть pdf файл через стандартный ридер компьютера, т.е. если при ручном открытии файл открывался в хроме, то по нажатию кнопки из программы файл открылся в хроме. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Process.Start (ваш pdf ) ?

Comment: блин, да, пробовал это сначала, но что-то Process не определялось. Забыл добавить пространство имён System.Diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

Открыть любые файлы

```
  using System.Diagnostics;
    //////////////
    Process.Start(filePath);
```